# How to store independent variables into an array as an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a CRUD application and I have this code snippet

```
state = {
            name: '',
            day: '',
            dob: '',
            items : []
        }

handleChange(event){
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value; //gets value of the textbox
        const name = target.name; //gets the name of the textbox

        this.setState({ [name]: value });

    };
handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
       /* the variables I want to store as an object in the items array          
        */
        const name = this.state.name;
        const day = this.state.day;
        const dob = this.state.dob;
      //array
        let items = this.state.items;

        items.push(name, day, dob);
        this.setState({
            items: items,
            name: '',
            day: '',
            dob: ''
         });

    };
```

from the code above, how can I store the variables `name, day` and `dob` as properties of an object into the `items` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it the same way you create your state object when calling `setState`: Using an object literal:

```
items.push({name, day, dob});
```

That's shorthand property syntax that does the same thing this does:

```
items.push({name: name, day: day, dob: dob});
```

---

Unrelated side note: There are a couple of places there you might benefit from using destructuring syntax. For instance, in `handleSubmit` this:

```
const name = this.state.name;
const day = this.state.day;
const dob = this.state.dob;
```

can be this if you like:

```
const {name, day, dob} = this.state;
```

Similarly in `handleChange`, you can destructure in the parameter list if you like:

```
handleChange({target: {name, value}}) {
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically all the values you mentioned are related to each other so you will be saving them as an object so that some time when you need to fetch them you will get a list of multiple objects

```
const {name, day, dob, items} = this.state;
items.push({name, day, dob});
```